# Yii Framework - multiple nested path and url for controller

Tags: yii, controller, subdirectory, yii-url-manager

Im working with Yii, and I'am trying to put my controller into subdirectory.
It works when subdirectory is only 1 folder long :

> Controllers / subdirectory / controller.php

But I'am forcing a problem when I want to have a path like this :

> Controllers/ subdirectory / subdirectory2 / controller.php

In my urlManager I do everything analogically as it's for single nested way, but i get error :

> The system is unable to find the requested action "subdirectory2"

So, it seems like Yii by defoult only understands in path the first subdirecotry as folder and second subdirecotry already considers as action, when i would like  be the very last part's of url, so i could also work for longer paths.

Best.

Comment: if you'de share your url managment rules, it would be nice

Comment: Perhaps you need [modules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module)?

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

It works in my way. Try to use this in your config file. Also there isn't problems with urlRewrite.

```
    'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => array(
            'test' => 'directory/subdirectory/test/index'
        ),
    ),
```